# Vertical alignment to center a text box inside a Command bar Content

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am having a problem trying to center (vertically) a text box inside a Command Bar Content.

Actually I have this (look at the last third line):

```
<CommandBar Grid.Row="0" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
    <AppBarButton x:Name="Back" Icon="Back" Label="Back" Click="Back_Click"/>
    <AppBarButton x:Name="Forward" Icon="Forward" Label="Forward" Click="Forward_Click"/>
    <AppBarButton x:Name="Refresh" Icon="Refresh" Label="Refresh" Click="Refresh_Click"/>
    <AppBarButton x:Name="Cancel" Icon="Cancel" Label="Cancel" Click="Refresh_Click"/>
    <AppBarButton x:Name="Home" Icon="Home" Label="Home" Click="Home_Click"/>
    <CommandBar.Content>
        <TextBox x:Name="Value"  VerticalAlignment="Center" KeyDown="Value_KeyDown" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="880"/>
    </CommandBar.Content>
</CommandBar>
```

The problem is that I have seen some guides where people write exactly that an it worked for them... but for me not. I am no sure what to do, I have tried with grid, relative panels, stack panels, etc using the design view of the Visual Studio 2017 as I could but I haven't found a solution.

[image]

**P.S:** Both [@Xavier Xie - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50734801/7655838) and [@Jeff R.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50728806/7655838) found a way to aling it only when the labels of the app buttons are showed, when they aren't the textbox seems unaligned. **I'm looking for a way to aling it when they aren't showed *and* when they are showed.** (So the alignment must change by some way automatly when the label are showed or not). If that isn't possible I'm looking for at least aling it when the labels aren't showed (not like they anwsers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to set `VerticalContentAlignment="Center"` for CommandBar like the following:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar Grid.Row="0" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
        <AppBarButton x:Name="Back" Icon="Back" Label="Back" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        <AppBarButton x:Name="Forward" Icon="Forward" Label="Forward" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        <AppBarButton x:Name="Refresh" Icon="Refresh" Label="Refresh" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        <AppBarButton x:Name="Cancel" Icon="Cancel" Label="Cancel" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        <AppBarButton x:Name="Home" Icon="Home" Label="Home" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        <CommandBar.Content>
            <TextBox x:Name="Value"  Width="880"/>
        </CommandBar.Content>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

***[Updated on 2018/6/8]***
[image]

[image]

***[Updated on 2018/6/14]***

After a lot of tests and consult with my colleagues, we found a way to achieve your target.

> I am looking for a way to aling it both with label and without label. I'll update my question to explain that explicitly.

To achieve your target, let's first check [CommandBar styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299118.aspx). Please locate to `CompactOpenUp` VisualState. You could see that it applies an animation to `ContentTransform` and change its `Y` axis position. That's reason why the textbox will be vertical aligned when the CommandBar is opened.

```
<VisualState x:Name="CompactOpenUp">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y">
                                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{Binding TemplateSettings.CompactVerticalDelta, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
......
```

Inspired by this, we also could dynamically change the textbox's Y axis position to make it vertical aligned when the CommandBar is closed. Then, let's locate to `ContentControl` in the style. This control actually is used to host your TextBox. So, we can define a `TranslateTransform` for it like the following:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="ContentControl" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsTabStop="False" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                        <ContentControl.RenderTransform>
                            <TranslateTransform x:Name="ContentControlTransform"></TranslateTransform>
                        </ContentControl.RenderTransform>
</ContentControl>
```

After that, I believe you've known that we need to define an animation in `CompactClosed` visual state. But you need to think about if the value of `Y` axis is appropriate. How to calculate this value? Let's check the `CompactOpenUp` visual state. It binds `TemplateSettings.CompactVerticalDelta` as its `Y` axis position. The `CompactVerticalDelta` will be changed dynamically in different visual state. So, we need define a converter for calculating the value.

The converter class like the following:

```
public class CompactVerticalDeltaConverter:IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {

        return (double)value/2;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then, the `CompactClosed` visual state finally should like the following:

```
<VisualState x:Name="CompactClosed">
        <Storyboard>
             <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentControlTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y">
                  <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{Binding TemplateSettings.CompactVerticalDelta, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent},Converter={StaticResource CompactVerticalDeltaConverter}}"/>
             </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
         </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

For now, we have achieved your target. Please try it.

[image]

Comment: @EnderLook Jeff R's suggestion was correct. The `VerticalContentAlignment="Center"` actually works. The textbox is 
vertical aligned with the entire `AppBarButton`. The AppBarButton has Icon and label. When you set `IsOpen="True"`, you would see it's vertical aligned. Else, it looks like it's not vertical aligned, but it actually is vertical aligned. Please my updated reply.

Comment: Oh, I see. You've right so I'll upvote your answer. But I can't accept it because I am looking for a way to aling it both with label and without label. I'll update my question to explain that explicitly.

Comment: @EnderLook I've achieved your target. Please see my updated reply

Comment: I've just seen your reply, I'm sorry for not having seen it before. I feel ashamed for having to ask this, but... where have I to allocate the `VisualState` and `ContentControl`? I've tried to put it directly on `CommandBar.Content` but it says there is already a Content Property. I also tried to put it inside a relative panel alongside with the textbox and another UI element I've added but it says that an UIElementCollection can't have that. I also tried on `commanbar` but this time the error is IObservableVector. I've also tried outside, with `<Style TargetType="CommandBar" >` but no clue.

Comment: Like you can notice, I'm a noob in this stuff and no one of my attemps works. I'm so sorry.

Comment: @EnderLook It's OK. Please check my above updated reply carefully. I let you check the [CommandBar styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299118.aspx) document. You need to copy all the style into your `<Page.Resources></Page.Resources>` and apply it to your commandbar. The VisualState and ContentControl are in that style.

Comment: Please check the [XAML Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/xaml-styles), you might be not familiar with this topic. Then, you would know what I say.

Comment: If you also are not familiar with `converter` in UWP, please see [IValueConverter interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter).

Comment: Ok. Thanks you. I'll read that tomorrow (because right now it's late). P.S: when you said `You need to copy all the style` you mean literally all that huge style code or just the parts I actually need to set? Because that is already the default style of the command bar, so I don't think it's necesary copy all that, right? If I don't define something on my own style it'll automatically use the default value for that variable, or at least I've understood that on the quick look I've just done on the XAML style guide, no? Well, when I've the time I'll read it in greater depth.

Answer (score 1):

Since the CommandBar is a Content Control it supports the HorizontalContentAlignment and VerticalContentAlignment properties. Try this:

```
<CommandBar Grid.Row="0" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
```

Comment: Odd, it works for me fine. Although when the CommandBar is in Compact mode it does look like it is on the bottom instead of centered. When the CommandBar is in Normal size-mode, the TextBox is definitely centered for me.

Comment: May be possible that we have different version of C# or .Net? I've installed the last version of Visual Studio (v15.7.2) so I have C# 7.1 (*I think*) and I've Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlataform v6.1.4.